# PyCharm - OSError: Socket is closed

Tags: python, pycharm

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! How can this be resolved? The issue seems to be with netmiko/paramiko & it's interaction with the script.

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

with open('Devices.txt') as f:
    file_content = f.read().splitlines()


devices = list()
for item in file_content:
    tmp = item.split(':')  #tmp is a list
    devices.append(tmp)


for device in devices:
    net_device = {
        'device_type': device[0],
        'ip': device[1],
        'username': device[2],
        'password': device[3],
        'port': 22,
        'secret': device[3],  # this is the enable password
        'verbose': True
    }

    connection = ConnectHandler(** net_device)

    if not connection.check_enable_mode():
        connection.enable()


    #connection.config_mode()
    config_file = input('Enter configuration file for device type: ' + device[0] + ' with ip ' + device[1] + ':')
    print('Sending commnands to device ...')
    with open(config_file) as config:
        commands = config.read().splitlines()
    # print(commands)

    output = connection.send_config_set(commands)
    print(output)
    print('Disconecting ....')
    print('#' * 40)


    connection.disconnect()
```

## Above is the script.

Error:

"C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\Python Network Automation\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/Python Network Automation/Python Netmiko.py"

```
SSH connection established to 192.168.181.150:22
Interactive SSH session established
Enter configuration file for device type: cisco_ios with ip 192.168.181.150:Static Route Configuration.txt
Sending commnands to device …

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/Python Network Automation/Python Netmiko.py", line 37, in <module>
    output = connection.send_config_set(commands)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\Python Network Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 1620, in send_config_set
    output += self.exit_config_mode()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\Python Network Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\netmiko\cisco_base_connection.py", line 55, in exit_config_mode
    return super(CiscoBaseConnection, self).exit_config_mode(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\Python Network Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 1531, in exit_config_mode
    if self.check_config_mode():
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\Python Network Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\netmiko\cisco\cisco_ios.py", line 31, in check_config_mode
    return super(CiscoIosBase, self).check_config_mode(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\Python Network Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\netmiko\cisco_base_connection.py", line 37, in check_config_mode
    return super(CiscoBaseConnection, self).check_config_mode(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\Python Network Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 1496, in check_config_mode
    self.write_channel(self.RETURN)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\Python Network Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 422, in write_channel
    self._write_channel(out_data)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\Python Network Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 384, in _write_channel
    self.remote_conn.sendall(write_bytes(out_data, encoding=self.encoding))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\Python Network Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 846, in sendall
    sent = self.send(s)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\Python Network Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 801, in send
    return self._send(s, m)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\Python Network Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 1198, in _send
    raise socket.error("Socket is closed")
OSError: Socket is closed

Process finished with exit code 1
```

## Above is the error message received.

Comment: do you get this error everytime or sometimes?

Comment: Sometimes, after running the script a few times. It will work fine then I’ll get the Socket Closed error.

Comment: I have the same exact issue as you @EmmitTruth

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the remote device is refusing the connection for some reason. You are connecting mutiple times in a row. However, your code is good but needs some modifications.

> I know my is answer is quite late, but it might be useful for others facing the same issue.

1. I think reading the devices from a CSV file would be much more neat, easier, and more convenient. *You don't have to index the variable `device[0]`, `device[1]`, and so on.*

The CSV file must look exactly like:

```
device_type,ip,username,password,secret
cisco_ios,192.168.1.1,cisco,cisco,
cisco_ios,192.168.1.2,cisco,cisco,
```

You can open it in Excel to have pretty view.

> As you can see, the header row contains the approriate keys of Netmiko.

You also don't need to explicitly set ports `22` and `23` for `cisco_ios` (SSH) and `cisco_ios_telnet` (Telnet) respectively. You need to set it only if you created a [rotary-group and an ACL](https://community.cisco.com/t5/switching/how-change-ssh-default-port-on-router/td-p/2231329) on the network device to change the default ports.

> **The only drawback of reading data from a CSV file with `csv.DictReader()` is that data values are parsed as `str`. `"verbose": True` is not an option in this case, because it will be parsed as a string not a Boolean (`'verbose': 'True'`).**

> You can use `csv.reader()` instead of `csv.DictReader()` and manipulate the parsed data first.

2. Sending configuration from a file is already implemented as a function in `Netmiko`. Use `connection.send_config_from_file("config.txt")` instead. It reads the file and does the heavy lifiting for you.
3. Use a context manager `(with statement)` and remove the `connection.disconnect()`.

A complete explanation of the above recommendations:

```py
import csv

from netmiko import ConnectHandler

# File containing network devices
with open("Devices.csv") as f:
    csvfile = csv.DictReader(f=f)
    devices = [device for device in csvfile]

# print(devices)  # <--- See output below

for device in devices:
    print(f'Connecting to {device["ip"]}')
    with ConnectHandler(**device) as conn:
        print(f'Connection established to {device["ip"]}:{device["port"]}')

        if not conn.check_enable_mode():
            conn.enable()

        # Find the device prompt.
        # The slicing here ([:-1)] is to remove the `#` sign after hostname
        hostname = conn.find_prompt()[:-1]

        # If the input file is the same for all devices, then move it up before
        # the for loop, else keep it here
        config_file = input(
            f'Enter config file for {hostname} ({device["ip"]}): '
        ).strip()

        print(f"Sending commnands to {hostname}...")
        # Using `send_config_from_file` instead of `send_config_set`
        output = conn.send_config_from_file(config_file)
        # Don't forget to save the new config if you need to
        # output += conn.save_config()  # Uncomment this line to save the new config
    print(f"Disconnected from {hostname}")
    print("#" * 40)
    print(output)
    print("#" * 40)
```

When `devices` variable is printed, it looks exactly like:

```sh
[{'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
  'ip': '192.168.1.1',
  'password': 'cisco',
  'secret': '',
  'username': 'cisco'},
 {'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
  'ip': '192.168.1.2',
  'password': 'cisco',
  'secret': '',
  'username': 'cisco'}]
```